# the view doesn t show image

Tags: javascript, html, image

i have a image in the folder of the view but the view doesn t show the image and i really don t know why this is happending to my.
i tried the solution that this page suggest but it didn t work to me [Local image URL syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895035/local-image-url-syntax)

[image]

```
<br />
<hr >
<img src= "C:\Users\Raul del Rio\Desktop\grupo-29\app\views\Ajax2\load.jpeg" alt="Trulli" width="500" height="333"/>
<p> his page was loaded asynchrously through a Ajax request.
 This page was loaded asynchrously through a Ajax request 
 This page was loaded asynchrously through a Ajax request 
 This page was loaded asynchrously through a Ajax request 
 This page was loaded asynchrously through a Ajax request 
 This page was loaded asynchrously through a Ajax request 
 This page was loaded asynchrously through a Ajax request 
 This page was loaded asynchrously through a Ajax request 
 This page was loaded asynchrously through a Ajax request 
 This page was loaded asynchrously through a Ajax request 
 This page was loaded asynchrously through a Ajax request 
 </p>
 <hr >
 <br />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local image URL syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895035/local-image-url-syntax)

Comment: i tried that but it didn t work

Answer (score 0):

You can see your desire out by replacing all backslashes `(\)` with forward slashes `(/)` and adding `file:/` as a prefix of the file path like following:

```
<img src="file:/C:/Users/Raul del Rio/Desktop/grupo-29/app/views/Ajax2/load.jpeg">
```

**Caution:**
But please remember your image path should be on a relative instead of absolute.
It will not work when you deploy it to a web server and it is a security issue of the modern browser.